# Script to transfer data into a list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on building a script that will transfer data from the first sheet to the second. Basically, we have three stores. When they want something from the "stock," the number will be put in the respective cell under their store beside the item they're requesting. When things are sent, I want to take all the values and move it to a running list of transfers, including the item, quantity, store, and date. I have the sheet laid out so you'll be able to see what I mean.

I'm a little rusty on scripts as I haven't built one in over a year. The following script does more or less what I need it too, with the exceptions:

1. It puts the date the whole way down the spreadsheet instead of just in the rows with other data.
2. I'll need to be able to repeat this process, and I'm fairly unfamiliar with the "lastRow" process.

Sample sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1irdT53jwiiJ56eMy33Kw7V51_Q2Nh0SCtdyoQfibSRE/edit?usp=sharing

Current code:

```
  var StockSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Stock');
  var TransferSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Transfers');

  var HTTransfer = StockSheet.getRange('B4:D');
  var CBTransfer = StockSheet.getRange('B4:E');
  var WBTransfer = StockSheet.getRange('B4:F');

  var Transfers = TransferSheet.getRange('B3:E');
  var ItemCol = TransferSheet.getRange('B3:B');
  var QuantityCol = TransferSheet.getRange('C3:C');
  var StoreCol = TransferSheet.getRange('D3:D');
  var DateCol = TransferSheet.getRange('E3:E');
  var SSItemCol = StockSheet.getRange('B4:B');
  var HTQCol = StockSheet.getRange('D4:D');
  var CBQCol = StockSheet.getRange('E4:E');
  var WBQCol = StockSheet.getRange('F4:F');

  var TransVal = Transfers.getValues();
  var ItemColVal = ItemCol.getValues();
  var QuantityVal = QuantityCol.getValues();
  var StoreVal = StoreCol.getValues();

  var SSItemVal = SSItemCol.getValues();

  var HTQVal = HTQCol.getValues();
  var CBQVal = CBQCol.getValues();
  var WBQVal = WBQCol.getValues();

  var today = new Date();

  for (var row in TransVal) {

    var todayData = today[row];

    var TransData = TransVal[row][0];
    var ItemColData = ItemColVal[row][0];
    var QuantityData = QuantityVal[row][0];
    var StoreData = StoreVal[row][0];

    var ItemData = SSItemVal[row];

    var HTQData = HTQVal[row];
    var CBQData = CBQVal[row];
    var WBQData = WBQVal[row];



  if (HTQData > 0) {

    ItemColVal[row][0] = ItemData;

    QuantityVal[row][0] = HTQData;

    StoreVal[row][0] = "Hagerstown";
    DateCol[row] = todayData;





  }}

  ItemCol.setValues(ItemColVal);
  QuantityCol.setValues(QuantityVal);
  StoreCol.setValues(StoreVal);
  DateCol.setValue(today);
}
```

Comment: Specifying ranges in this manner `getRange('D4:D');` is going to cause you problems with a lot of nulls at the bottom try it this way 'getRange(4,4,sheet.getLastRow()-3,1)`  Also the more data you can  get a one time  will help your function run faster.  Your seem more than just a little rusty.

Answer (score 0):

As @Cooper said, using ranges with A1 notation can be tricky, as it will select empty rows from the bottom of the range.

To work around this, you can:
- Use [`getLastRow`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)
- Use [`getDataRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) and then filter your data

The "translation" of `getRange('D4:D')` using `getLastRow`, you will have to use something like `getRange(4,4,sheet.getLastRow()-3,1)`.

However, since most of your data is from row 3 or 4, you could instead do something like:

```
var data = StockSheet.getDataRange();
var formattedData = data.getValues()
          .splice(3) //Removes the first 3 rows of data (the headers)
          .map(rowToData); //Returns an array of objects with all the columns as properties.
```

```
function rowToData(row) {
  return {
    "item": row[1],
    "stock": row[2],
    "hagerstown": row[3],
    "chambersburg": row[4],
    "waynesboro": row[5],
  };
}
```

*Code based on: [this range](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1irdT53jwiiJ56eMy33Kw7V51_Q2Nh0SCtdyoQfibSRE/edit#gid=0&range=B2:F6).*

[image: Range in question]